# the spark failed to establish a connection with the local machine

Tags: apache-spark

spark run in the Alibaba Cloud serve and i can not ping my local server from the server
When submitting a Spark job to a remote cluster from IntelliJ IDEA and trying to retrieve the result back to the local machine, spark unable to establish a connection with the local machine
`Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to LAPTOP-HQ3SVFP8:54605 at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:284) at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:214) at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:226) at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:204) at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:202) at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:198) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: LAPTOP-HQ3SVFP8`

how to do with that?